# Automating Nightly Build

Tags: perl, command-prompt, autoit

I am wondering how to trigger an AutoIt script on another PC from my own PC? Please be as descriptive as possible, I am moderately new to networking and remote commands.

Example:

- Nightly build Perl script begins
- Nightly build is successful
- Nightly build Perl Script triggers an AutoIt smoke-test on a separate PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) and [Windows Remote Shell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555966).

Comment: @Evan, would you believe it never occurred to me that this might have anything to do with Microsoft? I think I don’t have a very PC version of PC.

Comment: @tchrist AutoIt is a freeware Windows automation language.  http://www.autoitscript.com/  I assume this is what Christopher means by Auto-it smoke-test.

Comment: I guess I should have mentioned, that the command needs to be sent to the test PC without locking the test PC. The PC's UI needs to be 100% interactive for Autoit to run properly.